# Why the C standard C11 isn't default in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, standards

If you look at the [standards](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) you can see that they do include support for both C11 and C99. But if you try to compile a code without specifying the standard the GCC will still use the C89/C90.

What is the reason behind this?

I mean in other languages generally whenever a new standard is released the compiler will be set to follow the new rules.

Why this behavior isn't the same with the gcc compiler?

Comment: No. I am talking about [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29).

Comment: @FoggyDay Both C and C++ had new standards published in 2011, with C11 being the C language standard released that year.

Comment: ANSI C was/is recommended for GNU code, which could be one reason why.

Comment: I don't think he is. The linked document even includes the text "A fourth version of the C standard, known as C11, was published in 2011 as ISO/IEC 9899:2011."

Comment: @Skurmedel, my question is exactly what's the reasoning behind sticking with the ansi (c89/c90) C.

Comment: it defaults to gnu89, so by default gcc isn't working as a C compiler.

Comment: note that [according to the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), *"The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu90`; this is intended to change to `-std=gnu11` in some future release."*; I wouldn't hold my breath, though - it used to say the same thing about `gnu99`...

Comment: thank god, now the text has changed to `The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu11.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the page you linked:

> GCC supports three versions of the C standard, **although support for the most recent version is not yet complete.**

Support for C99 is substantially complete, but I think there are a couple of minor things that haven't been implemented yet.  According to that page, they intend to make C11 with GNU extensions the default in a future version.

Comment: they also intended to make C99 with GNU extensions the default, and I'm still waiting for that to happen...

Comment: @Christoph: yeah, each new version is adding some non-trivial bits to the language (VLAs, extended numeric capability, threads), and if they haven't finished C99 support by now, C11 support ain't gonna happen.

Answer (score 6):

99.99% of code written for C90 will compile cleanly under a C99 compiler, but not 100%. Since GCC is really the backbone of a Unix installation, with the implicit assumption that newer compilers won't break older software, absolute backwards compatibility is of the highest priority. It's easier to explicitly specify C99 for new software, than it is to go back and audit all the old software to see which bits need to be explicitly kept back to C90.

Comment: I understand, but wouldn't be preferred to make people evolve their code? And use the `-std=c90` if they don't want to change? It appears that the `gcc` community advocates *old school mentality* and don't want to evolve.

Comment: You need to define "preferred". As a computer user, would you prefer to have some of your software no longer work if you dared to upgrade your compiler?

Comment: Yes, considering that it would be to enforce better practices.

Comment: @DeMarco: It's scary to inherit code that you have no idea what it does, upgrade a compiler, and suddenly it doesn't so much as compile and you don't know why. (I've been there)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Scarier when new optimizations - or slightly changed ones - silently break your assumptions about UB (where you should not have made any anyway).

Comment: @DeMarco "better practices"? Best practice is to make code robust, stable, and bug-free. Changing language versions is sometimes a useful tool in support of that, but not always, and not by assumption.

Comment: Is there any authoritative source for your assertions? Especially as the reason you give is not met due to enhanced optimization and such-like...

Comment: It's always trivial to add `-std=gnu89` or `-std=c89` to `CFLAGS` when compiling old software, if necessary. So I don't think "not breaking old software" is a strong argument. I'd much rather see old software that's C99-/C11-incompatible break *by default* (with an easy way to fix it with `CFLAGS`) so that it would get fixed rather than rotting.

Comment: @Deduplicator The official line is that C99 will become the default ["when it's done"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html). Given that C99 support in GCC is as close to done as it'll ever be, it seems reasonable to assume that the GCC maintainers don't really have the appetite to break backcompat.

Comment: In the newer manual they want to move directly to gnu11: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

Comment: @R.. `configure; make; make install` is trivial. Anything beyond that is nontrivial.

Comment: @Sneftel: Good luck finding a package where that works unless you're running the exact same distro/version as the package author. Between differing library versions, stupid things like `-Werror` in default `CFLAGS` breaking as soon as the compiler authors add a new warning, assumptions about the filesystem layout, there's usually at least *something* you need to tweak...